# Splitting string into strings

Tags: python

Is there any way to split a string into many (not just 2) strings at a character, allowing blank strings, with the string names and order known? For example:

`john..doe.1985` would split into `first = 'john'`, `middle = ''`, `last = 'doe'`, and `dob = 1985`?

Comment: Obviously, both answers are just as good, just needed to pick one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> first, middle, last, dob = 'john..doe.1985'.split('.')
>>> first
'john'
>>> middle
''
>>> last
'doe'
>>> dob
'1985'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `split` method and iterable unpacking:

```
>>> first, middle, last, str_dob = "john..doe.1985".split(".")
>>> dob = int(str_dob)
>>> first
'john'
>>> middle
''
>>> last
'doe'
>>> dob
1985
```